# Getting content from external div

Tags: php, parsing

I need to get content from external page.

For example:

Let's use this site: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page` I need to get

only content of `"On this day..."` so it means div with `id="mp-otd"`

How can I do that with PHP?

Comment: try `PHP DOM parser`

Comment: Use any of the PHP DOM parser. There are a lot of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by suing `PHP DOM parser`

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page');
$div_content = $html->find('div[id=mp-otd]', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to download library from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

for example

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find specific 
foreach($html->find('div #mp-otd') as $element) 
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
```